# Craigslist 403 Blocking urlopen but NOT requests.get

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, urllib

Recently Craigslist.com started 403 blocking the following code.  This seems to be regardless of header or IP.

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from lxml import etree

url = 'https://sd.craigslist.org/search/sss'
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url_request = Request(url, headers=headers)
                      
webpage = urlopen(url_request,timeout=20).read()
```

This outputs the following:
`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

When I run a similar block using *requests* instead of *urlopen* it works fine.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
x=requests.get("https://sd.craigslist.org/search/sss")
tree = html.fromstring(x.content)
print(x.content)
```

Any help is appreciated. This seems like a new issue since none of the solutions proposed in previous posts has seemed to resolve.

Comment: Run both through a proxy e.g Postman and see what the difference is between the requests, there must be some difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exact same issue as you had. I was able to solve it with help from someone from the Scrapy team.

The issue will likely be resolved if you go into your `settings.py` file and add the following:

```
DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD = "TLSv1.2"
```

Then run your crawler again and this time it should work. I still don't know why this fixes the problem, so if anyone else knows why, it would be great if they could shed some light on this.

You can also refer to [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4951) Github issues I made to track any further responses from the Scrapy team regarding the issue.